# step size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangeslider

I am using the excellent rangeslider.js by Andre Ruffert

I have one question.
I have the slider set up so my numbers increase in increments of 6 as I move the slider along like so: 6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60

However I want the slider to increase by increments of 12 when it reaches 36 thus skipping out '42' and '54' so that when I move the slider it can be pulled along to the following: 6,12,18,24,30,36,48,60

is there a way that i can do this in js or html?

This is the code that should set up the slider values but for some reason this doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
        var valMap = [6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60];
        $("#term").rangeslider({
            min: 6,
            max: valMap.length - 1,
            value: 24,
            slide: function(event, ui) {                        
                $("#amount").val(valMap[ui.value]);                
            }       
        });
```

I can't get the JavaScript functions to overwrite  the HTML code for the slider which reads like this:

```
<input type="range" name="term" min="6" max="60" step="6" value="36" data-rangeslider>
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the value on `onSlide` event and change the step property of the slider once its reached 36:

```
var $r = $('input[type=range]');
onSlide: function(position, value) {
    if (v>=36) {      
      $r.data().plugin_rangeslider.step = 12;
    }
    else {
      $r.data().plugin_rangeslider.step = 6;
    }
}
```

Check [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEpKRw)

EDIT:

The values: min, max and value you should put as attributes on the html element and not while initializing. Also there is no `slide` function.
Look at this example ([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myGBVQ))

```
$("#term").rangeslider({
    polyfill: false,
    onInit: function() {
        $ruler[0].innerHTML = getRulerRange(this.min, this.max, rulerStep);
        this.$range.prepend($ruler);},
    onSlide: function(p,v) {
        if (!$("#term").data().plugin_rangeslider)
          return;
        if (v>=36) {      
          $("#term").data().plugin_rangeslider.step = 12;
        }
        else {
          $("#term").data().plugin_rangeslider.step = 6;
        }
    },
    onSlideEnd: function(p, v) {
        $('#val').attr('value', v)
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of rangeslider.js you can do, based on the accepted answer:

```
var $r = $('input[type=range]');
onSlide: function(position, value) {
    if (v >= 36) {      
        this.step = 12;
    }
    else {
        this.step = 6;
    }
}
```